# Historic count of casenumbers with no closeddate in a specific week

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, comparison

In SQL server I have two queries.
Query 1 shows me the months and weeks of the current year.
Query 2 shows me a specific type of cases with unique casenuber, createddate, closeddate and status.

When the Status of a case is 'New' or 'Running' the Closeddate is NULL. When the Status of a case is 'Cancelled' or 'Closed' there will be a Closeddate.

So here are my 2 queries.

Query1:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT YEAR(DAG_CODE) AS Jaar,
YEAR(DAG_CODE) * 100 + MONTH(DAG_CODE) AS Maand,
YEAR(DAG_CODE) * 100 + DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DAG_CODE) AS Weeknr
FROM [firstsource]
WHERE DAG_CODE BETWEEN '2024-01-01 00:00:00' AND GETDATE()
```

Query2:

```
SELECT
CaseNumber,
CreatedDate,
ClosedDate,
Status
FROM [secondsource] 
WHERE Createddate >= '2023-01-01 0:00:00'
```

Note that query 1 starts in 2024 and query 2 starts in 2023.

Now what I am looking for is a query that gives me the weeknumbers from the first query until now, and the count of all casenumbers of query 2 that at the start of that specific week (from query 1) on mondaymorning 0:00:00 still had Closeddate NULL.

As soon as there is a closeddate the casenumber should not be counted in the next week. But: I want to retrieve a historic overview on how many Cases were still open every week.

To show what is in the data, here are results of both queries:

First query gives the following table:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>year</th>
<th>month</th>
<th>week</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2024</td>
<td>202401</td>
<td>202401</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2024</td>
<td>202401</td>
<td>202402</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2024</td>
<td>202401</td>
<td>202403</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2024</td>
<td>202401</td>
<td>202404</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2024</td>
<td>202401</td>
<td>202405</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2024</td>
<td>202402</td>
<td>202405</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Second query gives these results:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Casenumber</th>
<th>Createddate</th>
<th>Closeddate</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1001</td>
<td>1-12-2023  15:33:44</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>Running</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1002</td>
<td>1-12-2023  15:33:44</td>
<td>1-1-2024  09:01:16</td>
<td>Closed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1003</td>
<td>16-01-1-2024  15:00:33</td>
<td>16-1-2024  09:01:16</td>
<td>Cancelled</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1004</td>
<td>18-01-1-2024  15:00:33</td>
<td>23-1-2024  09:01:16</td>
<td>Closed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1005</td>
<td>19-01-1-2024  15:00:33</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>New</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have to post some sample data and expected results in some sort of text table format

Comment: Thanx for the feedback, newbie here :-0. I made some pics of results from both queries and in yellow what I expect.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the pics is worse than no data at all. That's why it says "text table" and not "screenshot of table". Someone have to enter the data to write the code, and it's much easier to do it from text than image

Comment: OK sorry. Had no idea that someone actually will be working in the data. Gimme some time, I will edit the pics into a table.

Comment: Second table will follow in an hour...

Comment: We need sample *input* data not just expected results. And by tabular data we mean using markdown tables as shown in the answer (click edit on the answer to see how its done)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement properly, this looks like two separate tasks.
First, we want to know the weeks a case was open for, up to the current completed week.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, StartDateTime DATETIME, EndDateTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Table (StartDateTime, EndDateTime) VALUES
('2023-12-01', '2024-01-01'),
('2023-11-01', '2024-01-01'),
('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01'),
('2024-01-01', '2024-03-01');

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.ID, a.StartDateTime AS ThisDate, DATEPART(YEAR,a.StartDateTime) AS Year, DATEPART(WEEK,a.StartDateTime) AS Week, a.EndDateTime
  FROM @Table a
 UNION ALL
SELECT a.ID, DATEADD(WEEK,1,a.ThisDate), DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(WEEK,1,a.ThisDate)), DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK,1,a.ThisDate)) , a.EndDateTime
  FROM CTE a
 WHERE a.ThisDate < DATEADD(WEEK,-1,a.EndDateTime)
   AND a.ThisDate < DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE())
)

SELECT c.ID, c.ThisDate, c.Year, c.Week, c.EndDateTime
  FROM CTE c
 ORDER BY c.ID, c.Year, c.Week;
```

| ID | ThisDate | Year | Week | EndDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 48 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2023-12-08 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 49 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2023-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 50 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2023-12-22 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 51 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2023-12-29 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 52 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 44 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-11-08 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 45 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-11-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 46 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-11-22 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 47 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-11-29 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 48 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-12-06 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 49 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-12-13 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 50 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-12-20 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 51 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-12-27 00:00:00.000 | 2023 | 52 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-01-08 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 2 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 3 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-01-22 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 4 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-01-29 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 5 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 1 | 2024-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2024-01-08 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 2 | 2024-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2024-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2024-01-22 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 4 | 2024-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2024-01-29 00:00:00.000 | 2024 | 5 | 2024-03-01 00:00:00.000 |

Here we're using a recursive CTE to find all the weeks between the start date and the week prior to the end date, or prior to the current date.

Second, you want a list(?) of the IDs which are open, for each week any are open(?). If you want to expand this to ANY weeks you'll likely want to involve a calendar table, so you don't get blanks for any weeks which had no tickets at all.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, StartDateTime DATETIME, EndDateTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Table (StartDateTime, EndDateTime) VALUES
('2023-12-01', '2024-01-01'),
('2023-11-01', '2024-01-01'),
('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01'),
('2024-01-01', '2024-03-01');

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.ID, a.StartDateTime AS ThisDate, DATEPART(YEAR,a.StartDateTime) AS Year, DATEPART(WEEK,a.StartDateTime) AS Week, a.EndDateTime
  FROM @Table a
 UNION ALL
SELECT a.ID, DATEADD(WEEK,1,a.ThisDate), DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(WEEK,1,a.ThisDate)), DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK,1,a.ThisDate)) , a.EndDateTime
  FROM CTE a
 WHERE a.ThisDate < DATEADD(WEEK,-1,a.EndDateTime)
   AND a.ThisDate < DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE())
)

SELECT a.Year, a.Week, STRING_AGG(CAST(a.ID AS VARCHAR(10)),', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ID) AS OpenIDs
  FROM CTE a
 GROUP BY a.Year, a.Week
 ORDER BY a.Year, a.Week;
```

| Year | Week | OpenIDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 44 | 2 |
| 2023 | 45 | 2 |
| 2023 | 46 | 2 |
| 2023 | 47 | 2 |
| 2023 | 48 | 1, 2 |
| 2023 | 49 | 1, 2 |
| 2023 | 50 | 1, 2 |
| 2023 | 51 | 1, 2 |
| 2023 | 52 | 1, 2 |
| 2024 | 1 | 3, 4 |
| 2024 | 2 | 3, 4 |
| 2024 | 3 | 3, 4 |
| 2024 | 4 | 3, 4 |
| 2024 | 5 | 3, 4 |

Here we do much the same as before, but then group the result by week and use `STRING_AGG` to produce a comma separated list of the IDs open during that week. I added the optional `WITHIN GROUP` syntax to return the IDs in order.

Comment: Many thanx for your time! Will bring this back to work and check if this is what we are looking for. Will come back with results!

Comment: we managed to combine these 2 queries with ChatGPT and now we have what we need.  I will post the query that gave us the requested data. Many thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So we tried again and we managed to combine the two queries. The problem was that we could not join properly. This is what did the trick:

```
WITH Weeks AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
YEAR(dag.DAG_CODE) AS Jaar,
YEAR(dag.DAG_CODE) * 100 + DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, dag.DAG_CODE) AS Weeknr,
YEAR(dag.DAG_CODE) * 100 + MONTH(dag.dag_code) as maand,
MIN(dag.DAG_CODE) AS StartOfWeek
FROM [table_1] dag
WHERE dag.DAG_CODE BETWEEN '2024-01-01 00:00:00' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY YEAR(dag.DAG_CODE), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, dag.DAG_CODE), 
YEAR(dag.DAG_CODE) * 100 + MONTH(dag.dag_code) 
),

OpenCases AS (
SELECT 
c.CaseNumber,
MIN(c.CreatedDate) AS StartOfWeek,
MAX(c.ClosedDate) AS ClosedDate
FROM [table_2] c
WHERE c.RecordType_DeveloperName__c = 'Klacht'
GROUP BY c.CaseNumber)

SELECT 
w.Jaar,
w.Weeknr,
w.maand, 
COUNT(DISTINCT oc.CaseNumber) AS OpenCases
FROM Weeks w

CROSS JOIN OpenCases oc
WHERE oc.StartOfWeek < w.StartOfWeek
AND (oc.ClosedDate IS NULL OR oc.ClosedDate >= w.StartOfWeek)
GROUP BY w.Jaar, w.Weeknr, w.maand
ORDER BY w.Jaar, w.Weeknr
```